# How to force users to specify `-target=module.<environment>` when running `terraform apply`?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform script that provisions a web service on AWS.

Now I want to reuse this script in different environments (production, stage, dev, ...).

Here's my folder structure:

```
.
├── main.tf
└── core_module
    ├── outputs.tf
    ├── my_service.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

`main.tf` contains something like the following:

```
module "prod-service" {
  source = "./core_module"
  env_specific_variable = "this is a production environment"
  ...
}

module "stage-service" {
  source = "./core_module"
  env_specific_variable = "this is a stage environment"
  ...
}

module "dev-service" {
  source = "./core_module"
  env_specific_variable = "this is a dev environment"
  ...
}
```

When I want to create the service on the production environment, I run

```
terraform apply -target=module.prod-service \
  -var 'access_key=<prod_access_key>' \
  -var 'secret_key=<prod_secret_key>' \
  -var 'region=<prod_region>
```

And when I want to create the service on the stage environment, I run

```
terraform apply -target=module.stage-service \
  -var 'access_key=<stage_access_key>' \
  -var 'secret_key=<stage_secret_key>' \
  -var 'region=<stage_region>
```

How can I force the users of this script to add the `-target` option so that he/she doesn't create all the environments in one single command?

Because different environments require different `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`, running `terraform apply` to create all environments will create errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to force variables to be set or to be validated. I don't know of a way to enforce something in that `target` command line attribute. You'd have to use. variable instead and then change your main.tf to only deploy the environment specific version of the module based off some check if that variable.

However, it looks like you aren't using Terraform how it iis ntended. There is a concept called workspaces you should use to manage state of different environments instead of creating duplicate resources in one script for all the different environments.

To create a new workspace use something like

`terraform workspace new development`
`terraform workspace new staging`

The create a variables file for that environment

development.tfvars

```
variable env_specific_variable {
  default = "this is a dev environment"
}
```

staging.tfvara

```
variable env_specific_variable {
  default = "this is a staging environment"
}
```

Then in main.tf you deploy just one instance of your module and use the workspace specific environment instead of a literal string.

main.tf

```
module "my-service" {
  source = "./core_module"
  env_specific_variable = var.env_specific_variable
  ...
}
```

To deploy development use

```
terraform workspace select development
terraform apply
```

To deploy staging use

```
terraform workspace select staging
terraform apply
```

Note I am typing this on mobile and haven't ran this. There might be typos or syntax issues depending on your TF version.

Resources:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html
https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa (good article on general, but specifically check out the section on isolating workspace)

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that the `-target` argument is appropriate for. [The Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting) is explicit that the `-target` argument is for exceptional situations only, and gives some advice on what to do instead:

> This targeting capability is provided for exceptional circumstances, such as recovering from mistakes or working around Terraform limitations. It is *not recommended* to use `-target` for routine operations, since this can lead to undetected configuration drift and confusion about how the true state of resources relates to configuration.
>
> Instead of using `-target` as a means to operate on isolated portions of very large configurations, prefer instead to break large configurations into several smaller configurations that can each be independently applied. Data sources can be used to access information about resources created in other configurations, allowing a complex system architecture to be broken down into more manageable parts that can be updated independently.

In your case, I'd recommend to make each environment a separate Terraform configuration with its own separate Terraform state. Since you've factored out your environments into a shared module, each of them will contain only the `module` block to call it:

```
module "service" {
  source = "../../modules/core"
  env_specific_variable = "this is a production environment"
  ...
}
```

A common directory structure for this approach is:

```
environments/
  prod/
    main.tf
  stage/
    main.tf
  dev/
    main.tf
modules/
  core/
    variables.tf
    service.tf
    outputs.tf
```

To apply changes to a specific environment:

```
cd environments/prod
terraform init
terraform apply
```

By configuring Terraform like this, you avoid the need to force users to add extra options to their Terraform executions by using Terraform in the standard way. The environment configurations being separate has other benefits too, such as being able to use different provider versions in different environments in case you want to try rolling out a new version on your staging environment first before changing the production configuration.

Comment: @Martim Atkins what are the benefits to using folders per environment like this vs workspace per environment as in my answer? I have seen your pattern a few times lately but it is new to me. I see the benefits of using folders in your answer, but you can do the same things with workspaces afaik. This is not a criticism and I am genuinely trying to learn.

Comment: There's some longer-form info on that in [When to use Multiple Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces). The short answer is: workspaces only separate the state, and not the input variables or the backend configuration.